# Youtube view count embedded to HTML using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, view, youtube, count

I ain't very experienced with coding, so i am just asking for someone to put a code together for me, probably not advanced at all, i am using this code for a website i am building in HTML:

```
  $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=Qq7mpb-hCBY&key=[KEY]', function(data) {
document.write("viewCount: " + data.items[0].statistics.viewCount);
```

});

That is the code i currently use, but the "document.write" doesn't work, as it deletes the rest of the HTML page. 
What can i use instead of "document.write"? I know there is all the innerHTML, but i don't understand it enough, and i can't get it to work with the way the rest of the code is made.
Maybe someone could figure out a script for me so i can actually get this youtube view count on my HTML page as text.
Thank you
If you guys don't understand what i am doing, then ask, i am simply trying to put the data of the youtube video onto my HTML page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery `append` function will append the content to the body.

```
$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=Qq7mpb-hCBY&key=AIzaSyDwBd3B-BdNIglXT44obKjINRe5c6tRFvQ', function(data) {
    $('body').append("viewCount: " + data.items[0].statistics.viewCount);
});
```

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks, but it seems a little hard to move it around, i can't put the whole script into <center> etc. Is there a way around that?

Comment: You could change the append to `$('body').append("<center>viewCount: " + data.items[0].statistics.viewCount+'</center>');`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: amazing! Thank you for your help, i think i'll figure out the rest :))

Answer (score -1):

$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=Qq7mpb-hCBY&key=[KEY]', function(data) {
document.write("viewCount: " + data.items[0].statistics.viewCount);

$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=Qq7mpb-hCBY&key=AIzaSyDwBd3B-BdNIglXT44obKjINRe5c6tRFvQ', function(data) {
$('body').append("viewCount: " + data.items[0].statistics.viewCount);
});

Comment: Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74510831/edit) your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.